# Angular 4/Angular 2 validate SPA against Azure B2C Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, azure, azure-active-directory, angular2-services

In Angular 4/Angular 2 app, I want to validate it against Azure B2C Active Directory. In ASP.NET MVC, it was done using [Authorize] attribute on Controller and using an OWIN Startup.cs class to generate the authentication challenge and generating the Bearer token.

Moving on to a SPA application using Angular 4/Angular 2, I am not able to find a relevant tutorial for the same. I have seen some examples using Auth0, but I am not looking for an Auth0 solution. I want to authenticate directly against the Azure B2C Active Directory.

Can some approach and relevant example and tutorial describing the same be provided.

Tried ng2-adal sample suggested by 'Fei Xue - MSFT' below. Adding ng2-adal sample error message pics.

[image]
[image]

Added 'package.json' code:-

```
    {
  "name": "angular2-azure-ad",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "build": "tsc",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular2-adal": "^0.1.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "del": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, we need to implement [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) interface in the Angular 2 for the  guard deciding if a route can be activated.

To protect the SPA for the Angular 2 using Azure AD you can refer [this code sample](https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/ng2-adal-QuickStart). And about the Azure AD B2C authentication, you can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi).

Comment: I tried to run the 'ng2-adal-quickstart' sample. project.json had beta versions of angular core and others, so updated them to latest versions. Then installed ng2-adal using 'npm install angular2-adal --save'. ng2-adal looks for beta packages of angular core and others. On trying to run the project using 'npm start' also desplays several errors.

Comment: There is a issue when using the `jasmine` library. To fix this issue, after you clone the project from Github, please modify the package.json for this library using `"@types/jasmine": "=2.5.36"` instead of `"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"`

Comment: I have added 'package.json' code in my original post. It doesn't have jasmine at all from the sample downloaded from GitHub.

Comment: @Bobby please refer the line 54 of [package.json](https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/ng2-adal-QuickStart/blob/master/package.json#L54). And feel free to let me know if you still have the issue.

Comment: Xue MSFT : This is working only for Azure B2B AD and **not working for Azure B2C AD**. I need to provide the B2C SignIn policy. (1) How can I make it work with B2C Azure AD? (2) How can I fetch the Token as a string as I need to pass the Bearer token to authenticate & call a REST service? (3) How do I list the claims?